# Cant getting result from child activity

Tags: android

I have a Parent activity which is sending data to child activity but the child is not returning the result. I posted portion of code from both activity altogether below- Theres a few code that I didnt post for unnecessity.

```
    public class TdeeActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int CALLED_ACTIVITY = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tdee);
        Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent bmr= new Intent(TdeeActivity.this,BMRActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(bmr,CALLED_ACTIVITY);
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
        case CALLED_ACTIVITY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "THE RESULT-"+data.getExtras().getString("result"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}  // end class

public class BMRActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmr);
       Button btnOk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
       btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult();
            }
        });

        public void showResult() {


            Intent data= new Intent();
            data.putExtra("result",result);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();



    }   



}




}// end class
```

Comment: please post the piece of code that is raising exception..

Comment: Fisrt I need to get the result which I m not getting..pls look at the code.....NullpointerException occures ONLY when using this -getCallingActivity().getClassName() in child activity

Comment: Its hard to find the issue without the code that is causing the error and the logcat stack trace...

Comment: As I said, its not causing any error bro, simple not returning the result from child activity, wud u just see if theres anything wrong in my code

Comment: For the moment I m not using -getCallingActivity().getClassName() which is causing the NullpointerException error BUT I M NOT using it now

Comment: Now I just want to get the result from the child activity with the ABOVE code....but i m not getting any returned result

Comment: Do you know if `onActivityResult()` is being called at all? If so, what are the parameters?

Comment: How do I know it. I posted onActivityResult() overridding method above.

Comment: To see if `onActivityResult()` is being called at all, put a log statement or toast above your switch statement (e.g., `Log.d("onActivityResult", "requestCode: " + requestCode + " resultCode: " + resultCode);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you code in a dummy project and it was working fine at my end.. following is the code for both activity:

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CALLED_ACTIVITY = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent bmr = new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(bmr, CALLED_ACTIVITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
        case CALLED_ACTIVITY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "THE RESULT-"+data.getExtras().getString("result"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}


public class ChildActivity extends Activity {

    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Returning result from child activity
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("result", "from child"
                + this.getCallingActivity().getClassName());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

So please post more code so that issue can be found..

Comment: see the edit code now, I deleted some unnecessary code which is 160 line long

Comment: does your showResult() method is getting called? is the variable result in non null?

Comment: Thanx everybody, I got my problem. actually I was calling a child activity from a parent activity which was also called from a grand parent activity. startActivityForResult was put in the wrong activity. Thanx everbody.